# Adding ellipsis dynamically and keeping text in single line

Tags: html, css

Need to add text/span dynamically and still keep all newly added text/span in single line by adding an ellipsis;

When I have fewer text like 2 or 3 I get to see the complete text. But, only when dynamically adding text/span; I need these ellipsis to be added to it and still be in the single line...

I am not sure whats breaking the css here... (Ignore the border added!)

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 600px;
  height:25px;
  float:left;
}
.crumbs {
  width:24%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <span class="crumbs">TestTest--1--TestTest</span>
  
  <span class="crumbs">TestTest--2--TestTest</span>
  
  <span class="crumbs">TestTest--3--TestTest</span>
  
  <span class="crumbs">TestTest--4--TestTest</span>
  
  <!-- <span class="crumbs">TestTest--5--TestTest</span> -->
</div>
```

Also at https://jsfiddle.net/w30u0Lc8/

Comment: Nothing is breaking the css there; you've chosen a width that is large enough that none of the text needs to overflow.  If you set `.breadcrumbs` width to something smaller you'll see the ellipses showing up just fine.

Comment: Your fiddle appears to showcase all five elements accommodating ellipsis correctly (although by default your text isn't long enough to need ellipsis, which is why you're not seeing any). What exactly is the problem with your above code?

Comment: My Bad, adding the fifth/sixth span/text goes to the next line and ellipsis is not appearing!

Comment: each span is 24% wide, so if you added more it would have to go the next line.

Comment: rather going to next line I want the ellipsis to work and squeeze all in the single line...how can it be done ? As span increase so is ellipsis...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the `width:24%` is too large. Your span's aren't larger than that, so no ellipsis are added. Changing it to 10% works for example.

**edit**

If you want something that updates the width of the items automatically and adds ellipsis only when needed, then I'd suggest that you use flexbox instead.

See this example:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container')

setInterval(function () {
  if (container.children.length < 10) {
    var child = document.createElement('span');
    child.innerText = 'Some text';
    container.appendChild(child);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

It will add a new span every second. As you can see, the size of the children is automatically updated and ellipsis added when necessary.

Comment: I got that but when I have fewer text like 2 or 3 I get to see the complete text. But, only when dynamically added text/span increases I need these ellipsis added to it and still be in the single line... https://jsfiddle.net/w30u0Lc8/8/

Comment: @Santa_612 I've updated my answer with a solution that I think should work for you.